# App Engine and Firebase Hosting in One Domain

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

I have a custom domain (`travelbox.id`) that connected to Firebase Hosting already. I also have an App Engine application to serve as my API. I want to host the App Engine application on `api-dev.travelbox.id`. I mapped the custom domain to App Engine following [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) docs but domain connection to Firebase Hosting stop working. If you access [api-dev.travelbox.id](http://api-dev.travelbox.id/) it is connected to App Engine. But if you access [travelbox.id](https://travelbox.id/) it doesn't connected to Firebase Hosting.

Is that impossible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Wait a few hours for your DNS entries to change around the world. If you still have a problem, edit your question and include your DNS settings for `travelbox.id` and `api-dev.travelbox.id`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Could you put your comment as an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself, here you go!

On the fourth step in [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) docs, i didn't add A records, just add AAAA records. Suprisingly, it works! :D

Comment: Will this inhibit users of IPv4?

Comment: AAAA Records are for ipv6
So now you linked the main domain in ipv6 to the api.
So I think you should remove the AAAA records and only add the CNAME record

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and contacted Google Cloud support, here's their answer:

> App Engine doesn't need to have the A records on the root domain if
>   you are only serving from a subdomain.  App Engine should work
>   properly for you with just the one CNAME on subdomain.example.com.

Comment: This is the correct answer, works as expected. Give it a moment for the DNS records to propagate.

Comment: Thanks. Added only CNAME and it worked.